# Linux Mint 18 Scroll Direction Stuck

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

I just installed Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon, 64 Bit. I can't seem to get touchpad scrolling to be "normal" (instead of "natural"). In System Settings, I've tried toggling the "Reverse scrolling direction" switch in the touchpad tab of the Mouse and Trackpad Section. It doesn't seem to have any effect. Help?

Answer (score 4):

Mouse Preferences > Touchpad > unselect/disable "Enable natural scrolling" option.

Comment: Note that there are separate controls for mouse and touchpad --- I was failing to change the direction of the touchpad scrolling because what I was actually doing was changing the direction of mouse scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me.  I also just installed Linuxmint 18 Cinnamon 64 bit.  Noticed the opposite scrolling action and am not used to it.

Menu > Mouse and Touchpad > Scrolling > Reverse Scrolling Direction

Switching to OFF immediately changed it to normal, i.e. finger down scrolls down.

The GUI is

```
cinnamon-settings mouse
```

Try running that from a terminal to be sure you're using the same thing?